# how do we submit each row

Tags: jquery, ajax, button, click

I need to submit each looped rows. In my current situation its submitting only my first row. Whenever clicked on the submit button , it should execute only that particular row. How can I solve this?

screenshot: https://ibb.co/x8y6X94

// my form

```
 <form action="">
                <table class="table table-hover table-centered m-0 table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Designation</th>
                            <th>Account Number</th>
                            <th>Attendance</th>
                            <th>Rate</th>
                            <th>Loan </th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="salaryData">
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </form>
```

below code shows, data fetching from the databse, and this data inserting to tbody , tbody id is #salaryData

```
success: function(data) {
                    // alert('test');
                    var html = '';
                    var i;
                    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        html += '<tr>' +

                            '<td>' + data[i].emp_name + ' </td>' +
                            '<td>' + data[i].cat_name + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + data[i].emp_account_number + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' +
                            '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="attendance"  name="attendance" placeholder="Attendance" required>' +
                            '</td>' +
                            '<td>1</td>' +
                            '<td>' +
                            '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="loan"  name="loan" placeholder="Loan" required>' +
                            '</td>' +
                            '<td>' +
                            '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary item-edit" id="btnSave">Submit</a>' +
                            '</td>' +

                            '</tr>';
                    }
                    $('#salaryData').html(html);
```

// submit code

```
$(function() {

    $('#salaryData').on('click', '.item-edit', function() {
        var row = $(this).closest("tr")
        var attendance = row.find("[name=attendance]").val();
        var loan = row.find("[name=loan]").val();

        $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url  : "<?php echo site_url('con_salary/testSalary')?>",
                dataType : "JSON",
                data : {attendance:attendance , loan:loan},
                success: function(data){
                    if(data==1 ){
                        $('#btnSave').prop('disabled', false);


                    }
                    else{
                        $('#btnSave').prop('disabled', true);

                    }
                }
            });
            return false;




    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to ensure that any `id`s you have in the DOM **are unique**. Right now, you're using `id="btnSave"`, `id="attendance"`, and `id="loan"` repeatedly in the table. But your click handler is set up correctly (using delegation and `.item-edit`), and as far as I can tell you can just get rid of those IDs.

Within the click handler, use `this` or `event.currentTarget` to refer to the button that was clicked. You can get the row for that button by using [`closest("tr")`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/). Then you can find the attendance and loan inputs via [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) using their `name`s.

So for instance:

```
$(function() {

    $('#salaryData').on('click', '.item-edit', function() {
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        var attendance = row.find("[name=attendance]").val();
        var loan = row.find("[name=loan]").val();

        alert(attendance);

    });
});
```

Live Example:

```js
$(function() {

    $('#salaryData').on('click', '.item-edit', function() {
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        var attendance = row.find("[name=attendance]").val();
        var loan = row.find("[name=loan]").val();

        alert(attendance);

    });
});

var data = [
    {emp_name: "Joe Bloggs", cat_name: "cat1", emp_account_number: 1234},
    {emp_name: "Muhammad Al-Rashad", cat_name: "cat2", emp_account_number: 5678},
    {emp_name: "Elena Gonsalez", cat_name: "cat2", emp_account_number: 9876}
];
// alert('test');
var html = '';
var i;
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    html += '<tr>' +

        '<td>' + data[i].emp_name + ' </td>' +
        '<td>' + data[i].cat_name + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + data[i].emp_account_number + '</td>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="attendance" placeholder="Attendance" required>' +
        '</td>' +
        '<td>1</td>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="loan" placeholder="Loan" required>' +
        '</td>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary item-edit">Submit</a>' +
        '</td>' +

        '</tr>';
}
$('#salaryData').html(html);
```

```html
<div id="salaryData"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much its is working perfectly. I do have one more doubt, If the the response true i mean form data inserted, How do we disable the submit button. Can you please check the submit code, I have updated that code what I have written for disabling. Its disabling only fist button.

Comment: @VishnuJayaraj - You can't disable a link. I'd suggest using a proper button instead (either an `input="button"` or a `button type="button"`), which you *can* disable. You can style a `button` element to look just about any way you want it to look.

Comment: Yes its true. My problem is disabling first button only. Whenever submit the button  need to disable the button if response is true

Comment: @VishnuJayaraj - As I said above, the button will be `this` (or `event.currentTarget` if you accept an `event` parameter to your event handler). So instead of `var row = $(this).closest("tr");` you'd have `var btn = $(this); var row = btn.closest("tr");` and then later when you want to disable the button, use `btn`.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function() {
    $('#salaryData').on('click', '.item-edit', function() {
        var Selected = $(this).closest('tr');
        var attendance = $('#attendance', Selected).val();
        var loan = $('#loan', Selected).val();
        alert(attendance);
    });
});
```